# A Bell-Ringing One! (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word

Hi I'm finally back with a new Riley!

NOTE: As someone has voted to close my question, I have put effort into rephrasing the question. Please tell me if this is still too broad. Thanks!

Riddle me this:

> The prefix is what's left after we minus me, 
>  The infix is where you get a warm hot bath.
>  The suffix is a means by which we travel, 
>  And yeah, that's me, and does my name ring your bell?

Hint 1:

> U

Hint 2:

> There are some redundant parts in the riddle, just to match the rhythm.

Hint 3:

> Where can you see a bell?

Hint 4:

> The second line can be rephrased as follows: 
>  The infix is in which you enjoy the heat.

Hint 5:

> Hi, this is Suffix speaking. I am properly a noun, not like those commoners, so think twice before you think you find me

Comment: Nice one! I'm stumped on the prefix. Could it be "they"?

Comment: You might enjoy having rep, Omega, and that is not a bad thing — it is what makes Puzzling so addictive, essentially. But imho, you shouldn't ask for rep. Users will +1 you accordingly (including myself), depending on whether they like your content or not, and it might come across as selfish to ask for rep. I'm not trying to be harsh, but rather humble, though this is my opinion after all; I am just pointing it out to ensure a friendly environment in this community. You might not think you add much, here, but considering this is your 10th Riley (congrats btw), then I think you do. $(+1)$ :P

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take your suggestion seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix is what's left after we minus me,

> we = (you and me) - me = you = U

The infix is where you get a warm hot bath.

> in the tub

The suffix is a means by which we travel. Credit goes to @NudgeNudge

> Uber, like the taxi company.

And yeah, that's me, and does my name ring your bell?

> So we get u-tub-er, i.e. **youtuber**. The only thing about bell ringing is the taxi driver ringing on your door bell.

Comment: Infix correct, Prefix correct but wrong explanation, suffix wrong. Pay attention to the last line of the riddle! Keep it up, +1, coz this is the nearest answer so far

Comment: Prefix and infix correct, will add hint for suffix soon

Comment: Done as promised!

Comment: Maybe suffix is rot13(Hore, nf va gur gnkv freivpr pbzcnal? Znxvat gur svany jbeq "lbhghore"). Not sure how that fits the "rings a bell" part though.

Comment: @NudgeNudge I thought about the same but it contradicts hint 5. Also my answer was similiar initially but then I changed it followining the comments.

Comment: But it's the suffix that hint 5 is concerned with isn't it? That would make the suggestion correct I think.

Comment: @NudgeNudge I see your point. I'll try it.

Comment: Well done, answer correct! But the bell I'm talking about is the notification bell those youtubers always ask the audience to turn on

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> [Shellcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcraft)

The prefix is we minus me plus he,

> us - "u" + "he" = **she**

The infix is, in particular, an enjoyment of heat.

> Hell

The suffix is by which from place to place you travel,

> Craft - for example, a boat or ship.

And yeah, that's me, and does my name ring your bell?

> Shellcraft designs are often presented in bell jars. 
>  [image]

Comment: Very interesting though, but sorry you are wrong. Keep it up, +1!